# How to Persist N Value Objects in an Aggregate Root

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot, value-objects

In DDD, in an aggregate root of Person with a Value Object of Address, mapping that address to a database table is simple: just embed the attributes of the Address object into the record. But what about when the Person has a List, where the count can vary? Do we create a separate table that stores all our Addresses (thereby imposing some quasi-identity on each one), and each row with an FK back to the Person to which it belongs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good example of object-relational impedance mismatch. What you can do is have a layer super-type where persistence concerns such as an id field lives. Therefore, from your persistence layer's point of view, the VO is an entity, but still modeled as a VO in the domain.

You can read more about the above [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=X7DpD5g3VP8C&pg=PA255&lpg=PA255&dq=layer%20supertype%20value%20object&source=bl&ots=tRBNLGze_O&sig=HZDWRKoXbX3lyhlQ5cUqA7m3JiY&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=2DA4Vb69LdHmarSWgagG&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=layer%20supertype%20value%20object&f=false).

Comment: Thanks for the insight and the link. I know this is off topic but in your opinion is NHibernate superior to Entity Framework for the task of supporting DDD?

Comment: @BCA, I never used Entity Framework unfortunately, but Vaughn Vernon blogged on how to efficiently use Entity Framework https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=879